# Retrieve part of string from one word to another or to the end

Tags: java, regex

I have a following lines in my file:

```
/rootfolder/test/a/b/c/magicword/blabla
/rootfolder/test/a/b/c
```

All these lines should match a regex pattern.
In addition, I need to find a group between `/rootfolder` and `/magicword` or if there is no `/magicword` - till the end.
So, for my two lines above, the 1st group should be `/test/a/b/c`.

I have tried `/rootfolder(?|(?>(/.*)(?>/magicword).*)|(/.*))` (with escaping of /). It works well for some online regex validators, but so far no luck to use it in Java.

Is there any chance to make such regular expression using Java?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Example of working regex: https://regex101.com/r/cJkIJH/1 . The same result I need in Java.

Edit2:
Thanks to the answers below look like `/rootfolder(.*?)(?:/magicword.*|$)` works perfectly for my conditions.

Comment: @Nexevis I used it, but the problem is with `?|` as there is no such token in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy here just use this regex and work with capture group #1:

```
/rootfolder(.*?)(?:/magicword.*|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nuK808/2)

Non-capturing group `(?:/magicword.*|$)` matches end of line or `/magicword` and rest of line after `.*?` (lazy match).

Comment: That looks almost perfect, but what I need in addition is to have all line as a full match for expression. I suppose that if I change it to `/rootfolder(.*?)(?:/magicword.*|$)` it will fit my conditions. Blame me if I'm wrong :D

Comment: Yes you are right, just be adding `.*` after `magicword` will make it match full line.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support a branch reset group `(?|`

You might simplify your expression using an optional non capturing to match from `/rootfolder` to `/magicword` and inside use a capturing group matching what comes before `/magicword`

```
^/rootfolder(?:(.*?)/magicword)?.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1dLZmX/1)

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to have the 1st group as `/test/a/b/c` and full line should match my expression. Something like this https://regex101.com/r/cJkIJH/1 but for Java

Comment: Then you could use `^/rootfolder(.*?)(?:/magicword.*|$)` https://regex101.com/r/AYSXNr/1 But that is a small addition to @anubhava 's answer. His answer would solve your problem.